# useEffect calls the state indefinitely or not at all

Tags: reactjs

I am building an example dApp project. I get some values from smart contract and call my API to return data which works fine. But when I'm setting a state in `getMyNFTs` function, it starts to get called indefinitely.

So I have put [myNFTs] in my useEffect because I know it happens when I call the setState in that function and want to stop calling it multiple times, but now it is not getting called at all. Am I using the useEffect hook wrong?

```
let [myNFTs, setMyNFTs] = useState([]);
let wallet = [];

useEffect(() => {
    getMyWallet();

    return () => { }
}, [myNFTs]);

async function getMyWallet() {
    if (currentAccount.length > 5) {
        wallet = [];
        const ContractObj = importSmartContract;
        wallet = await ContractObj.methods.walletOfOwner(currentAccount).call();
        getMyNFTs(wallet);
    }
}

async function getMyNFTs(wallet) {
    let postRes = await axios.post('http://localhost:10000/receivedMints', { "list": wallet }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.result);
        setMyNFTs(response.data.result);
    }).catch(err => {
        toast.error(err.message);
    })
}
```

Comment: Is your useEffect/useState inside a React component? I'm not even sure if you're using it correctly.

It would be a good idea to create an example that allows people to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Your effect hook depends on `myNFTs` so it will execute when that changes (when you call `setMyNFTs()`). Your effect hook results in a call to `setMyNFTs()` so it will enter an infinite loop. When do you want your effect hook to execute?

Comment: It's in React component. It's a page in App.js, a route like this:<Route exact path="/myNFTs" component={myNFTs} />

Comment: I actually want to get the data from API when my page loads and set it so I can map it in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array as the second argument to `useEffect` says: "When there are changes to these values, trigger the callback function".

`useEffect` always gets called once initially. Which, in your case calls `getMyWallet` which may conditionally call `getMyNFTs` which calls `setMyNFTs` which is a dependency of the effect, thus looping.

You should reconsider what should really trigger the effect. If you just want to call it once on mount, then leave the dependency array empty.

You might rather only call `setMyNFTs` when `response.data.result !== myNFTs`.